# Initialization of virtual base class of abstract class

Tags: c++, constructor, abstract-class

Consider the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct A
{
    virtual void foo(){ };

    A()
    {
        cout << "A()" << endl;
    }
};

struct B : virtual A
{
    virtual void bar() = 0;

    B() : A() //mem-initializer of virtual base class
    {
        cout << "B()" << endl;
    }
};

struct C : B
{
    void bar(){ };
    C() : B()
    {
        cout << "C()" << endl;
    }
};

C c;

int main()
{
    //A()
    //B()
    //C()
    //Is output
}
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40ae35f88dea8b0d)

I've written the code to understand the rule's note from **12.6.2/8 N37973**:

> [Note: An abstract class (10.4) is never a most derived class, thus
>   its constructors never initialize virtual base classes, therefore the
>   corresponding mem-initializers may be omitted. — end note]

If we omit mem-initializer in the `B()` and make the base class `A` as non-virtual we'll have the same result.

[**Actually**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/013d6c8202662f55).

So what purpose of the note that I cited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's talking about something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct A
{
    virtual void foo(){ };

    // N.B.: no default ctor
    A(int)
    {
        cout << "A(int)" << endl;
    }
};

struct B : virtual A
{
    virtual void bar() = 0;

    B()
    {
        cout << "B()" << endl;
    }
};

struct C : B
{
    void bar(){ };
    C() : A(10), B()
    {
        cout << "C()" << endl;
    }
};

C c;

int main()
{

}
```

If `A` weren't a virtual base of `B`, or `B` weren't abstract, then `B::B()` must have an appropriate *mem-initializer* for `A`; however, since `B` is abstract and `A` is a virtual base, and `B`'s constructor will never actually construct `A`, the *mem-initializer* can be omitted. Note that g++ currently does not implement this rule and still requires a *mem-initializer* for `B` (which it will never actually use). Clang does, however. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ed25370645f988b).

See also [CWG issue 257](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#257), which introduced this rule, with the phrasing further altered later by [CWG issue 1658](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1658). The relevant GCC bug reports are [bug 19249](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19249) and [53878](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53878).

Comment: I still don't see the relevance of the Note in §12.6.2/8 (C++11). For example, it's enough to declare a default constructor for `A` (you don't need to define it) for the code to compile in GCC. IMHO the issue has nothing to do with the lack of a mem-initializer for `A` in `B::B()`, but the fact that the compiler doesn't find a default constructor for `A` when it's parsing `B`. If you just include this declaration in `A`, the problem is solved.

Comment: @Belloc The point is that that declaration isn't required by the standard. The fact that GCC requires it is a bug.

Comment: But that is not what issue 257 is complaining about: `Must a constructor for an abstract base class provide a mem-initializer for each virtual base class from which it is directly or indirectly derived? Since the initialization of virtual base classes is performed by the most-derived class, and since an abstract base class can never be the most-derived class, there would seem to be no reason to require constructors for abstract base classes to initialize virtual base classes.`

Comment: I was wrong. See this discussion https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/std-discussion/tHiKnvEp9-U

Answer (score 2):

If `B` inherits non-virtually from `A`, then `B`'s constructor must initialize the `A` base class subobject. Since `A` has a default constructor, you don't have to explicitly mention `A` in the *ctor-initializer* for `B`. However, if `A` did not have a default constructor, and `B` inherited non-virtually from `A`, you would have to explicitly initialize `A` in the *ctor-initializer* for `B`.

If `B` inherits virtually from `A`, and `B` is an abstract class, then even if `A` has no default constructor, you still don't need to mention `A` in the *ctor-initializer* for `B`. This is because `B`'s constructor will never have the responsibility of initializing the `A` subobject; instead, the most derived class's constructor is the one that has to initialize the `A` subobject, since `A` is a virtual base class.

Comment: See my comment to @T.C. above

Comment: @Belloc I'm sorry, I don't really understand your question.

Comment: See this discussion https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/std-discussion/tHiKnvEp9-U

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't demonstrate much, since the virtual base `A` has a *default constructor*. You never have to explicitly invoke default constructor for a virtual base class (or any base class for that matter). The compiler will invoke that default constructor implicitly everywhere it is needed, regardless of whether you've done it explicitly yourself.

Remove the default constructor and provide a constructor with a parameter in `A`

```
struct A
{
    A(int)
    {
        cout << "A()" << endl;
    }
};
```

The note in question is telling you that now you will have to explicitly invoke the constructor for base `A` from each *non-abstract* class virtually derived from `A` (directly or indirectly). In your case you have to explicitly initialize `A` from the constructor of `C`

```
struct C : B
{
    void bar(){ }
    C() : A(42)
    {
        cout << "C()" << endl;
    }
};
```

since C is not an abstract class.

But you don't have to initialize `A` from the constructor of `B`, since `B` is an abstract class. I.e. this

```
struct B : virtual A
{
    virtual void bar() = 0;

    B()
    {
        cout << "B()" << endl;
    }
};
```

should compile in C++11, even tough the "classic" (pre-C++11) language rules required an explicit initialization of `A` from the constructor of `B` as well.

Note that GCC compiler used by ideone (for one example), still reports an error for the above definition of class `B` even in C++11 mode. Apparently, it has not been updated yet to follow that rule of C++11.