# Virtual base class initialization

Tags: c++, constructor

Looking for an explanation of some fact in the standard I found this:

> An abstract class (10.4) is never a most derived class, thus its
>   constructors never initialize virtual base classes, therefore the
>   corresponding mem-initializers may be omitted.

This is from the paragraph `12.6.2` of the final working draft. Since, It's embedded in *Note* and no example is provided, I don't know how it should be treated. So, I tried the example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B{
    ~B(){}
    B(){ std::cout << "B()" << std::endl; }
    B(int){ std::cout << "B(int)" << std::endl; }
};

struct A : virtual B
{
    int s;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    A(int a) : B(a) { std::cout << "A(int)" << std::endl; }
};

struct D : A{ 
    D() : A(10){ }
    virtual void foo(){ }    
} d;

int main()
{
}
```

and got the output

```
B()
A(int)
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b16c68226f072ced

in spite of specifying the `B`'s constructor in the *ctor-initializer*. Is that what they mean?

Comment: (revising my comment) Yes, I think you got it right: `A(int)` skips the initialization of `B` even though you've used `B(a)` in the ctor-initializer. Eventually the default constructor of `B` is called to initialize it. (P.S. You want `virtual ~B() {}`.)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25397512/1062948) answer ought to be relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, `D` is the most derived class and will construct B using the default (no parameter) constructor.

An abstract class is never most derived because you have to derive from it in order to instantiate it.